# Позиционирование Trust Logo

Tags: javascript, css, cms, magento

Помогите, пожалуйста. Мне нужно установить отображение логотипа **Comodo TrustLogo** на сайте в правом нижнем углу так, как показано у них на сайте:

[image: код и место логотипа]

Также на это скрине видно код, который они предлагают вставить для такого отображение. Но когда я вставляю код, как написано в инструкции, то получаю вот такой вид, в котором логотип падает под футер:

[image: отображение логотипа]

Чтобы я не делал и куда бы не переставлял код, который на примере находится справа, ничего не меняется, логотип остается под футером. Так как само изображение приходит JS скриптом, то наложить стиль CSS я тоже на него не могу. Перелопатил весь интернет, почти всем помогает просто вставить этот код по инструкции. Потому есть мысли о том, что это может быть как-то связанно с самой CMS Magento. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться что я упускаяю. Для наглядности прикрепляю ссылку на свой код:

[image]

Comment: Перепишите ту часть вашего кода, в котором есть проблема, сюда в виде запускаемого сниппета.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите, какие разметку и стили выводит этот JS, и вставьте их в HTML и CSS соответсвенно. В CSS вы сможете сами доработать позиционирование изображения. К тому же, это позитивно скажется на производительности страницы за счет снижения внешних запросов. Не стоит вставлять на сайт JS-код, который вы легко можете заменить на HTML/CSS.

Comment: В том то и дело, что в разметку этот JS ничего не добавляет, ни дивов, ни классов, ни id. Приходит только <a><img></img><a> при наведении на который выскакивает popup.

Comment: @lasombras, а по-твоему, `a` и `img` - это не разметка?

Comment: @Qwertiy, объясните, пожалуйста, как можно привязаться к этим 'a' и 'img' , если они не единственные на странице, а родительского и дочерного у них нет.

Comment: @lasombras, можно попробовать обернуть во что-то. Можно `body > a > img`. Там смотреть надо, что он делает.

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы повысить приоритет стиля который формируется js скриптом используйте `!important`